# Concurrently execute SQL stored procedures / queries that all write to the same table from python

Tags: python, sql, multithreading

I have a time consuming stored procedure that needs to be run for multiple dates. The stored procedure takes a date as a parameter, and then writes to a table for each date you run it for (the same table, appending for each new date).

Is there a best practices way to concurrently run the stored procedure, or is it forced to run sequentially since you cannot afaik simultaneously write to a table?

I've tried using threads, and it took about as long or longer as just running sequentially would take.

Sample of relevant code:

```
def main():
    for date in last_workday_of_month('2015-10-31','2015-8-31'):
        t1=Thread(target=query,args=('time_consuming_stored_proc',date))
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

Comment: When you are updating a table, it will be locked from being edited or read (unless with a NOLOCK hint for a dirty read).  If you will be updating a huge portion of the table, you may want to split your transactions into batches, just make sure your changes are atomic though and that an error won't leave your table half updated.  If you are requesting a ton of updates at a time, they'll wait their turn before they execute.  If you are doing a bunch of operations on a table that is highly used, try to prepare everything outside away from it so you don't have to keep reading or updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL server, by designed, multiple threads can write data to a table simultaneously, or multiple users can write data into the same table.

So it depends on your design whether you need to protect a piece of your logical data from multi-thread reading/writing activities.

If, for example, your stored procedure just needs to add a NEW separated row into a table every time it runs, then perhaps you don't need to protect that row in the table from multi-thread writing.

If your stored procedure needs to write to a particular row at some time, for example a data row for the current date, and there is some possibility that your stored procedure can be called by multiple users at the "same time" (same date in the example), then you need some way to prevent your stored procedure from modifying that data row while another user is running your stored procedure.

If your stored procedure finds out that there is another user running it, you have two options: just exit the stored procedure or wait until the other procedure call finishes. There are several ways to detect the race condition. In SQL server, I normally use `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` for this purpose.

Hope this help.